# mdadm doesnt't work in secure mode

Tags: linux, mdadm

Im trying to mount /dev/sda1 in secure mode (cause of troubles with boot loader), but i cant do it without mdamd.

```
root@rescue / # mdadm
mdadm will not execute and completion _mdadm exists.
```

**So, how to use mdadm in secure mode?**

```
Linux rescue 5.4.2-arch1-1 #1 SMP PREEMPT Thu, 05 Dec 2019 12:29:40 +0000 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```